# Logging to multiple targets with Elmah

Tags: logging, elmah

I have the following Elmah configuration:

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql"  />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.MemoryErrorLog, Elmah" size="50"  />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
</elmah>
```

But I get this error when I run my application:

> Sections must only appear once per
>   config file.   See the help topic
>    for exceptions.

Comment: Can you post the `<configSections>` declarations and the rest of your Elmah config?

Answer (score 6):

You can only use one of each type of logger in Elmah. What you specify in the `<errorLog>` section is where Elmah logs it's data.

When you retrieve errors using the `/elmah.axd` handler it retrieves this data from the data source type specified in the `<errorLog>` section. It doesn't really make sense to have more than one, or at least it's not designed that way.

Comment: Interesting, I thought Elmah was like NLog, where you could specify multiple targets or in this case errorLogs.

Comment: @guanome - correct and indeed you can, but in the OP's case he is trying to specify multiple `<errorLog>` sections of the same name. He'd need something like `<errorLog>` for the primary log store where `/elmah.axd` would retrieve its data and `<errorLogMem>` & `<errorLogXml>` sections defined as alt log destinations. I probably didn't explain that very well in my answer. Unfortunately OP didn't respond to my request for him to post the `configSections/sectionGroup` of his web.config so my answer was best effort with the information available at the time.

Comment: @Kev, I want to know how to log to multiple target (especially in XML and Database) using Elmah, could you update your answer please?

Comment: @Willy - I don't have time to do this. You could ask a new question.